# how to implement polling iphone sdk?

Tags: ios, long-polling

I want to know how we can auto refresh a `uitableview` by using polling. I have a table which contains messages users sent. So when I load the view i use AFTNetworking to get the JSOn response and display it in the `uitableview`. Now if the user stays on the screen and we get a new message posted it should automatically refresh the `uitableview`.So far what I can do it to call the url at certain time intervals. Any solutions to that?

Comment: add refresh button in navigation bar and when user click on that send request after getting response add this line to refresh tableview [yrtableview reloadData];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Timer will invoke "loadNewData" after each 10 seconds

```
NSTimer *refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f target:self selector:@selector(loadNewData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

write your loading code in this method

```
-(void)loadNewData
{
    // write code to fetch Data from Server
}
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for your response wi ill try that and get back to you :)

Comment: i think this is wrong. Technically it will work but think about it, when tons of devices fetch requests from your server at a one time, what will happen ?, either i'm looking for solution for this also i did a some research at the end i stopped at node.js tcp/ip network programming, but i've no luck and finding solution over and over again .....